# Makefile Errors while building megasdk python in Alpine Edge Docker

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu, github-actions, alpine-linux

**I recently am facing problems on building MegaSdkC+ python wheel on alpine edge Linux docker ...I currently tried to port it via the Ubuntu Dockerfile**

**Error:**

```
#8 184.6 In file included from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:20,
#8 184.6 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:18,
#8 184.6 from ./include/mega/posix/meganet.h:28,
#8 184.6 from ./include/mega.h:74,
#8 184.6 from src/posix/net.cpp:22:
#8 184.6 src/posix/net.cpp: In constructor 'mega::CurlHttpIO::CurlHttpIO()':
#8 184.6 src/posix/net.cpp:272:10: error: converting to 'bool' from 'std::nullptr_t' requires direct-initialization [-fpermissive]
#8 184.6 272 | if (!CRYPTO_get_locking_callback()
#8 184.6 | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#8 184.6 src/posix/net.cpp:274:13: error: converting to 'bool' from 'std::nullptr_t' requires direct-initialization [-fpermissive]
#8 184.6 274 | && !CRYPTO_THREADID_get_callback())
#8 184.6 | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#8 185.1 make[2]: *** [Makefile:2767: src/posix/libmega_la-net.lo] Error 1
#8 185.1 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
#8 187.0 mv -f src/posix/.deps/libmega_la-waiter.Tpo src/posix/.deps/libmega_la-waiter.Plo
#8 187.0 make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/home/sdk'
#8 187.0 make[1]: *** [Makefile:3347: all-recursive] Error 1
#8 187.0 make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/home/sdk'
#8 187.0 make: *** [Makefile:1517: all] Error 2
```

**Here is the direct logs of the errors of which is built via github actions:**

**https://github.com/AmirulAndalib/MLTB-ALPINE-DOCKER/runs/7592589121?check_suite_focus=true#step:9:995**

***Tried to port from Ubuntu .. Dockerfile and Github Actions build logs are given below***

***Logs***

**https://github.com/AmirulAndalib/slumtoolkit0-docker/runs/7595322451?check_suite_focus=true**

***Dockerfile***

**https://github.com/AmirulAndalib/slumtoolkit0-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile**

***For alpine Build***

***Dockerfile***

**https://github.com/AmirulAndalib/MLTB-ALPINE-DOCKER/blob/master/Dockerfile%20Base/Dockerfile**

***Gitflow Logs***

**https://github.com/AmirulAndalib/MLTB-ALPINE-DOCKER/runs/7592589121?check_suite_focus=true**

***MegaSdkC Repository***

**https://github.com/meganz/sdk**

Comment: It is possible that the compiler has been upgraded, and that the new version of the compiler is stricter and is generating an errors on code that compiled with an older version of the compiler.  If so, then you have (at least) three options:  (a) fix the code, (b) use the old compiler, or (c) pass the new compiler the the `-fpermissive` flag.  I say this based on my general experience compiling source code, and not based on any particular experience with Python or Docker.

Comment: ```
configure.ac:53: installing './compile'
configure.ac:57: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:57: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:55: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:55: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
bindings/python/include.am:2: installing './py-compile'
Makefile.am:61:   'bindings/python/include.am' included from here
parallel-tests: installing './test-driver'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--fpermissive'
Try `./configure --help' for more information

```

Comment: `-fpermissive` is not an option for `./configure`.  `-fpermissive` is a compiler flag.  So you need to figure out how to pass flags to the compiler.  I'm not an expert, so I cannot provide detailed instructions.  Maybe look for the variables `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS`.  Or run `./configure --help` and see if it tells you how to set compiler flags.  The "best" way to solve the problem is to fix the source code, but it may not be the easiest way.

Comment: @mpb did you mean

```
OBJCXX      Objective C++ compiler command

  OBJCXXFLAGS Objective C++ compiler flags
  
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
  
  PYTHON      the Python interpreter


```

But I don't know how to pass these flags maybe check this


https://github.com/meganz/sdk/blob/master/Makefile.am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mpb I had added the `-fpermissive` flag as you told and the errors were actually downgraded to warnings also my built code is working very well

Fix :

https://github.com/AmirulAndalib/MLTB-ALPINE-DOCKER/blob/master/Dockerfile%20Base/Dockerfile#L45

thank you very much for helping